# Firebase Realtime Database security rule works in playground, but not in app

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In my Realtime Database I have a top-level entry named "users". It should be accessible to all authenticated users. The security rule is the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly when I test it in the playground, but when I try to access "users" in my Flutter app with the following code, I get the exception

> FirebaseException ([firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.)

Here is my Flutter code:

```
var usersRef = _realtimeDatabaseInstance().ref("users");

var usersSnapshot = await usersRef.get();
```

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: If this read is rejected against the rules you shared, logic seems to dictate that there is no user signed in when it runs. You'll want to check that with `if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @FrankvanPuffelen - sorry, clearly my fault. I used a Firebase instance initialized with a specific name for the Realtime Database, but the default Firebase instance for authentication. Fixing this solved the problem.

Comment: Good to hear you were able to fix the problem @iosdeveloper! 